# Import all XML files into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

How to correct this SQL query to read all XML files that exists in the `C:\Files\` folder and not just the `Test.xml` file?

```
CREATE TABLE Projet 
(
    UID int, 
    nom varchar(50), 
    prenom varchar(50), 
    matricule varchar(50), 
    lien varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO Projet (UID, nom, prenom, matricule, lien)
    SELECT
        page.value('(item[@name="UID(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]', 'INT') AS UID,
        page.value('(item[@name="nom(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS nom,
        page.value('(item[@name="prenom(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS prenom,
        page.value('(item[@name="matricule(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS matricule,
        page.value('(item[@name="lien"]/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS lien 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
         FROM 
             OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Files\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
    CROSS APPLY 
        MY_XML.nodes('root/page') AS MY_XML (page);
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version ( `SELECT @@VERSION;` )?

Comment: SQL Server version 19

Comment: Thats not what is returned if you run `select @@version`

Comment: Try following : https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-read-list-of-files-in-folder-using-t-sql

Comment: I will try, and I will return with a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to do this completely from SQL, which is not designed to do direct file access and is fraught with issues, instead use a proper scripting language such as Powershell to push the data into SQL.

You can use [dbaTools' `Invoke-DbaQuery`](https://docs.dbatools.io/Invoke-DbaQuery.html) to execute SQL commands with parameters. Simply get the contents of files you want and push them through in the pipeline as SQL parameters.

```
$sql = @"
INSERT INTO Projet (UID, nom, prenom, matricule, lien)
    SELECT
        page.value('(item[@name="UID(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]', 'INT') AS UID,
        page.value('(item[@name="nom(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS nom,
        page.value('(item[@name="prenom(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS prenom,
        page.value('(item[@name="matricule(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS matricule,
        page.value('(item[@name="lien"]/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS lien 
    FROM (VALUES(CAST(@xml AS xml)) v1(xml)
    CROSS APPLY v1.xml.nodes('root/page') AS MY_XML (page);
"@;

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Files\' |
  Get-Content -Raw |
  Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance 'YourServer' -Database 'YourDB' -Query $sql -SqlParameter @{ xml = $_ };
```

Comment: I tried running this SQL query, and I encountered an error. Can you determine the cause of this error?  ` Invoke-DbaQuery : Impossible de trouver un paramètre correspondant au nom « Parameters ».
Au caractère Ligne:14 : 93
+ ... V19C6\SQLEXPRESS' -Database 'mabase'  -Query $sql -Parameters @{ xml  ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Invoke-DbaQuery], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Invoke-DbaQuery`

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following solution.

It is a two step process:

1. Load file names from a directory into a table.
2. Loop through that table, shred XML, and load data.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Projet;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Projet (UID INT, nom VARCHAR(50), prenom VARCHAR(50), matricule VARCHAR(50), lien VARCHAR(100));

DECLARE @directoryList TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FullyQualifiedFileName NVARCHAR(255)
);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @directory NVARCHAR(255) = N'c:\Files\'
   , @fileWildcard NVARCHAR(10) = N'*.xml';

-- Step #1
-- Load file names from a directory into the @directoryList table
INSERT INTO @directoryList(FullyQualifiedFileName)
SELECT FullyQualifiedFileName = @directory + file_or_directory_name
   --, level, is_directory, creation_time, size_in_bytes
FROM sys.dm_os_enumerate_filesystem(@directory, @fileWildcard);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @directoryList;

-- Step #2
-- Loop through the @directoryList table, shred XML, and load data
DECLARE @FullyQualifiedFileName NVARCHAR(255)
   , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
   , @RowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @directoryList);

WHILE @RowCount > 0 BEGIN
   SELECT @FullyQualifiedFileName = FullyQualifiedFileName
   FROM @directoryList
   ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET @RowCount - 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
   
   -- do whatever needed, apply any logic, call stored procedures, etc.
   -- The variable you pass if doesn’t supported by the placeholder (%s, %i) then it will throw an error.
   SET @sql = FORMATMESSAGE('INSERT INTO Projet (UID, nom, prenom,matricule,lien)
SELECT page.value(''(item[@name="UID(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]'', ''INT'') AS UID,
    page.value(''(item[@name="nom(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]'', ''VARCHAR(50)'') AS nom,
    page.value(''(item[@name="prenom(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]'', ''VARCHAR(50)'') AS prenom,
    page.value(''(item[@name="matricule(Zonal OCR)"]/@value)[1]'', ''VARCHAR(50)'') AS matricule,
    page.value(''(item[@name="lien"]/@value)[1]'', ''VARCHAR(100)'') AS lien 
FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N''%s'', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes(''root/page'') AS MY_XML (page);', @FullyQualifiedFileName);

   PRINT @sql;
   EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

   SET @RowCount -= 1;
END

-- test
SELECT * FROM dbo.Projet;
```

Comment: Why not `SELECT @FullyQualifiedFileName = FullyQualifiedFileName FROM @directoryList WHERE ID = @i;` and use a normal loop counter?

Comment: It is also an option.

Comment: Just seems inefficient to keep doing `OFFSET` on each loop, even a cursor would be better than that.

Comment: To me it just immaterial. How many files could be in a directory...

Comment: I will try, and I will return with a response.